# wordpress is consuming a lot of CPU

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am from Chile, I have a website in wordpress that has been in 3 hosting but in all it consumes all the CPU, currently I am in siteground but the same thing happens, all my plugins are original, I have optimized everything (cache, images, etc) but no longer I know what to do.

[CPU SEOCONDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74H5g.png)

[Program executions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQqtW.png)

I check the logs of my server and I realize that when I enter a specific page (shop/page4/) it generates 82 "movements" and several of these are the same "POST/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP / 2.0 "200 516" https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/ "

```
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:27 +0000] "GET /superpwa-sw.js HTTP/2.0" 404 77606 
"https://goetia.cl/superpwa-sw.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.952 0.980 0.981 BYPASS W NC:200000 UP:SKIP_CACHE_NO_CACHE
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.099 3.123 3.124 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 120 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.392 3.416 3.416 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 516 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.067 3.093 3.094 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.534 3.570 3.569 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.541 3.568 3.567 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.504 3.531 3.531 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.472 3.509 3.509 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.356 3.384 3.383 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.317 3.347 3.347 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.298 3.326 3.325 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.208 3.239 3.238 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:23 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.187 3.213 3.213 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.125 3.165 3.165 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.118 3.165 3.165 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.105 3.131 3.131 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 3.053 3.080 3.080 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.975 3.005 3.004 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.958 2.984 2.984 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.927 2.965 2.965 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /?wc-ajax=xoo_wsc_refresh_fragments HTTP/2.0" 200 511 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.890 2.915 2.915 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.889 2.914 2.913 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.859 2.888 2.887 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.842 2.874 2.874 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.840 2.870 2.870 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.808 2.833 2.833 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.786 2.815 2.815 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.708 2.746 2.745 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.652 2.669 2.668 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.516 2.545 2.544 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.507 2.546 2.547 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.359 2.389 2.389 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.395 2.407 2.408 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:22 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.279 2.312 2.313 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.203 2.239 2.240 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.178 2.208 2.209 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.168 2.199 2.200 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.159 2.187 2.188 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.139 2.166 2.167 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.084 2.110 2.111 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.060 2.095 2.096 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 2.027 2.055 2.055 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.990 2.017 2.018 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.908 1.947 1.948 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.777 1.800 1.800 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.727 1.758 1.758 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.705 1.741 1.740 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.507 1.542 1.541 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.449 1.473 1.473 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.402 1.436 1.435 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.400 1.429 1.428 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.370 1.398 1.397 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:21 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.342 1.373 1.373 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.308 1.335 1.335 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.207 1.247 1.246 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.170 1.206 1.205 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 1.156 1.187 1.186 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.987 1.014 1.014 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.795 0.825 0.824 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.754 0.786 0.786 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.730 0.754 0.754 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.689 0.712 0.711 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.699 0.723 0.723 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.703 0.727 0.728 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 66 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.685 0.720 0.720 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:20 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 849 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 0.775 0.799 1.064 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Shaman_king_001-min-500x619.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 17320 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Tai_2-min-1-1-500x619.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 18034 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Slam_dunk_000-min-500x619.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 17382 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/matt_2-min-1-500x619.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 18624 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Given_001-min-500x619.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 17630 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Poke_baka_000-min-1-500x619.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 21784 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/side-cart-woocommerce/assets/css/fonts/Woo-Side-Cart.woff?le17z4 HTTP/2.0" 200 14700 "https://goetia.cl/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_48f973c3757389f3868bde33ea5c76fa.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Shaman_king_001-min-125x125.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 4486 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Tai_2-min-1-1-125x125.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 4486 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/matt_2-min-1-125x125.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 4455 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Given_001-min-125x125.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 4521 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Slam_dunk_000-min-125x125.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 4067 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/side-cart-woocommerce/assets/js/xoo-wsc-main.js?ver=2.1 HTTP/2.0" 200 5283 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:17 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Poke_baka_000-min-1-125x125.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 5138 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.000 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:17 +0000] "GET /wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_48f973c3757389f3868bde33ea5c76fa.css HTTP/2.0" 200 281678 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/4/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | - - 0.107 - W NC:200000 UP:-
179.56.48.145 goetia.cl - [13/Feb/2021:04:02:17 +0000] "GET /tienda/page/4/ HTTP/2.0" 200 105932 "https://goetia.cl/tienda/page/3/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" | TLSv1.3 | 7.097 7.130 7.630 BYPASS W NC:200000 UP:SKIP_CACHE_NO_CACHE
```

please help my webpage its down :(

Comment: The problem depends on the fonts. Which plugin do you use for the cache? WP-Rochet? Try to see here: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/24-resolving-issues-with-cdn-and-fonts-icons